# Multiplicar n números em c

Tags: c

Qual motivo do meu código, independente dos números digitados multiplicar com o número que coloquei para condição do laço ser falsa? Queria apenas multiplicar os valores que digitei e não multiplicar também o número para sair do laço.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int multi=1, val;

do
{
printf("Digite um valor");
scanf("%d",&val);
multi= multi*val;
}
while(val!=0);
printf("%d",multi);
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que está a ocorrer é que ao digitar o `0` ele vai multiplicar por `multi` e assim o resultado dá `0`

```
do
{
printf("Digite um valor");
scanf("%d",&val); // ao inserir 0
multi= multi*val; // multi= multi * 0
 }while(val!=0);  // para o ciclo
 // multi vai ter o valor de 0
```

A maneira de corrigir é não deixar o `0` multiplicar pelo `multi` e por isso, mal digite `0` para logo o ciclo, por exemplo:

```
  while(1) //ciclo infinito
    {
    printf("Digite um valor");
    scanf("%d",&val); // ao inserir o 0
    if(val==0) // val==0 -> true
        break; // sai fora do ciclo
    multi= multi*val; //multi NÃO multiplica por 0
    }
```

---

**Veja estas diferenças:**

```
while(1) // é igual a dizer `while(true)` ou seja, é sempre verdade, ciclo infinito
{
scanf("%d",&val); 
if(val==0) //o ciclo é parado AQUI
   break;
//caso val==0 este pedaço de codigo nao é executado
}
```

---

```
do{
scanf("%d",&val); 
//caso val==0 este codigo é executado
}while(val==0) // o ciclo é apenas parado AQUI
```

Apesar destes codigos serem muito semelhates pode fazer a diferença, como é este o caso.

**[Codigo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Yqhunc)**

---

Poderia tambem fazer desta forma:

```
int multi=1, val=1;
    do
    {
    multi= multi*val;
    printf("Digite um valor"); 
    scanf("%d",&val); // caso seja inserido 0
    }while(val!=0); // PARA logo o ciclo
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82506/discussion-on-answer-by-fabio-morais-multiplicar-n-numeros-em-c)

Comment: @Maniero Tem razão, começou surgir duvidas pelo meio. Obrigado por ter movido.

Comment: Isso é mensagem padrão do sistema, eu só aceitei a sinalização dele.

Comment: Postei uma pergunta duplicada pois não estava achando esse tópido!!! Obrigado @FábioMorais , desculpas!!